# Indoor floor maps in react native

Tags: navigation, react-native, maps, google-indoor-maps

I want in implement floor map navigation in my application. Please , suggest any available Library or ways to implement it.

Tried following, but does not allow to add customize map/floor etc.

```
<MapView
        style={styles.mapViewStyle}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 37.78825,
          longitude: -122.4324,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}>
        <MapView.Marker draggable
            // calloutOffset={MapView.Marker.Point{x:0, y:30}}
            pinColor='steelblue'
            coordinate={{latitude: 37.78825,longitude: -122.4324,}}
            title='San Francisco'
            description='City by the Bay'
            onDragEnd={(e) => this.setState({ x: e.nativeEvent.coordinate })}
          />
    </MapView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can customize something like [react-native-maps](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps) from Airbnb, for the implementation part, we don't provide code on-demand in this website, first you have to show us what you tried :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have tried this library, it provides support for maps, but adding custom maps or floor is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently searching for the same solutions. You can try to search the keyword, "indoor navigation" or "indoor mapping".
For now, there are some good libraries/SDKs that might support React-native (some may require you to implement natively):

- [Mapwize](https://docs.mapwize.io/)
- [Proximi.io](https://proximi.io/)
- [ArcGIS](https://developers.arcgis.com/)

Hope this helps!